# Subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ which extend to $\mathbb{C}$ via finite extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

The field **Q** is a subfield of **C** but it is in a sense "much smaller" than **C**. The field **R** however has a finite extension of order just two to the field **C**. My question is:

> Are there other subfields of **C** which are "finitely" less than **C**, or is **R** the only example?

I know that for such a subfield we would have automorphisms of **C** that fix the subfield and have finite order, but I have read that there do exist wild automorphisms of **C**, so we cannot discard that option in this way. I have also considered the intersection of such a subfield with **R**: it would itself be a subfield of  **R**. If we could conclude the extension from this subfield of **R** to **R** is finite we'd be done, because the only possible automorphism of **R** can be proven to be the trivial one. However, I'm not sure we can state that if **F** has a finite extension **G** then for some other field **H** we have that **F** $\cap$ **H** has finite extension **G** $\cap$ **H**.

Comment: Yes, there are other fields. The answer lies in model theory.

Comment: @ Asaf: for example?

Comment: Any real-closed field of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. (In fact, this gives an accurate characterization of such fields.)

Comment: but can you give an **explicit** example? or is it just an existence proof?

Comment: The axiom of choice plays a strong role in constructing examples. But you can easily show that any ultrapower of $\Bbb R$ by a free ultrafilter over $\Bbb N$ will satisfy these conditions and be non-isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I am not familiar with ultrapowers and ultrafilters ....

Comment: Which is why I was vague about the whole thing.

Comment: ok, so what would we adjoin to such a subfield to obtain the complex plane?... for reals its just the imaginary unit, for such subfields it is..

Comment: Just $i$ also...

Comment: really? so they're all extensions of order 2 then? interesting...

Comment: There's a theorem that says that an algebraic closure is a finite degree if and only if its degree is $2$.

Comment: https://books.google.fr/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&lpg=PP1&ots=IKy9T7D7C2&dq=algebra+serge+lang&pg=PA299&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 10):

A theorem of Artin and Schreier states that if $K$ is algebraically closed and of finite degree over a field $k$, then (1) the characteristic is zero; (2) the degree is two; and (3) $K=k(i)$, where $i^2=-1$. You can find it in Lang’s *Algebra*, and many other sources.

Comment: You can do no better than Keith Conrad's exposition on this topic: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf

Comment: Note, however, that for $K=\mathbb{C}$, there are many isomorphism classes of such subfields $k$.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a relatively simple example of such a subfield which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.  Consider the ordered field $\mathbb{R}(x)$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is given the usual order and $x$ is larger than every element of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $K$ be an ordered field which is maximal among all ordered algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ (such a $K$ clearly exists by Zorn's lemma).  It is not hard to show that every odd-degree polynomial over $K$ has a root in $K$, and every positive element of $K$ has a square root in $K$ (to prove this, show that if this failed, you could order an extension of $K$ in which you adjoin such a root).  One of the standard proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra shows that the field $K[\sqrt{-1}]$ is algebraically closed (see [this discussion on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Algebraic_proofs), for instance).  That is, $K[\sqrt{-1}]$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}(x)$.  It follows that $K[\sqrt{-1}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ (they are both algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero and transcendence degree $2^{\aleph_0}$).

Finally, I claim $K$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.  To see this, note that they are clearly not isomorphic as ordered fields, since $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedean but $K$ is not.  But the orderings on $\mathbb{R}$ and $K$ are completely determined by their field structure, since in both fields, an element is positive iff it has a square root.  Thus $\mathbb{R}$ and $K$ cannot be isomorphic as fields.

As a final remark, the result alluded to in Lubin's answer says more precisely that every example is of this kind: if $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a proper subfield such that $\mathbb{C}$ is finite over $K$, then $K$ can be given a (unique) ordering such that every positive element has a square root and every odd-degree polynomial has a root, and $\mathbb{C}=K[i]$.

Answer (score 2):

Under the axiom of choice there is an isomorphism $\sigma: \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{C}((x^{1/n}))\to \Bbb{C}$ so that $K=\sigma(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{R}((x^{1/n})))$ works,

$[\Bbb{C}:K]=2$ and there is no isomorphism $\rho:K\to \Bbb{R}$ since $\rho|_\Bbb{R}$ would be the identity.